# Google Play Store doesn't support .APK anymore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, apk, release

I am making an app with Unity and i prepared the app for release on Google Play (key and other settings)

But for some reason it doesn't let me upload .apk, only .aab. Last time i published a game (3 months ago) it worked with an .apk but for some reason it won't work now. Did miss something?

[image]

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By new google policy,  From August 2021, the Google Play Console will require all new apps to Publish with the Android App Bundle format so, Your build must be as **aab**. in unity for build as **aab** you must check **Build App Bundle (Google Play)** in **Build Settings**.
[image]

also for more detailed how to sign with previous sign key and setup aab see:

https://blog.unity.com/technology/support-for-android-app-bundle-aab-in-unity-2018-3-beta

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-app-bundle-google-play-app-signing-what-option-do-we-use-with-unity.604723/

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-app-signing-by-google.471539/#post-4618345

Comment: This means Google signs the APK rather than the developer. This eliminates the problem of developers losing their signing keys and being unable to update their apps. It also means Google can backdoor any app.